# C Number in Python

Tags: python, c

I'm reviewing some code that utilizes the `cytypes` library and I'm seeing some new things:

```
print("some_num : %04x" % [a c_uint32 number]) # [] used as placeholder
print("another  : %01x" % [a c_uint8 number])
print("another1 : %02x" % [a c_uint16 number])
```

I can tell there's a relationship with the formatting notation using `%` and the `ctype` number, but I'm unsure what that is.  Any help/pointers to some references would be much appreciated!

Comment: see this - https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  The `%x` formatting is for hexadecimal.  `%0Nx` means hexadecimal left-padded with zeros to at least `N` digits (e.g. `01` instead of just `1`).  This has nothing to do with them being ctype types though.

Comment: Your code snippet does not more than produce a hex representation of the number in appropriate length padded with zeroes. What is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- A `c_uint8` uses 1 byte (= 8 bits).
- A `c_uint16` uses 2 bytes (= 16 bits).
- A `c_uint32` uses 4 bytes (= 32 bits).

2 [hexadecimal digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) define a byte. It means the number before [`x`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting) should be a quarter of the number after `c_uint`. This way, all the hexadecimal numbers will have the same length.

```
print("another  : %02x" % [a c_uint8 number])
print("another1 : %04x" % [a c_uint16 number])
print("some_num : %08x" % [a c_uint32 number])
```

Here's a small test:

```
>>> from numpy import iinfo, uint8, uint16, uint32
>>> iinfo(uint8).max
255
>>> '1 byte : %02x' % 0
'1 byte : 00'
>>> '1 byte : %02x' % iinfo(uint8).max
'1 byte : ff'
>>> '2 bytes : %04x' % 0
'2 bytes : 0000'
>>> '2 bytes : %04x' % iinfo(uint16).max
'2 bytes : ffff'
>>> '4 bytes : %08x' % 0
'4 bytes : 00000000'
>>> '4 bytes : %08x' % iinfo(uint32).max
'4 bytes : ffffffff'
```

Answer (score 0):

To Print a c_uint variable 'var1', you need to do this:-

```
printf('the value of variable is %d', var1)
```